# Youtube Embed Code - Start and end parameters do not work on Android Stock Browser

Tags: javascript, android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm building a mobile optimised landing page for an app and I'm trying to get specific behaviour for the youtube embed code on mobile: the video should start and end at specific times in the video.

Here is the embed code:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/[ID]?html5=1&enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&modestbranding=0&controls=0&rel=0&start=10&end=20&loop=1"
        frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I am also creating an object from the code so I can handle the embedded video with the js api, and I'm also passing the same parameters through that just in case. (The iFrame html is created as a template when the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function is called.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

    var youtubeTemplate = $("#youtubeTemplate").html();

    $('#thumbnail-inner').html(_.template(youtubeTemplate, {
         //Params
    }));

    youtubePlayer = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        enablejsapi: 1,
        events: {
            'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'onError' : onPlayerError
        },
        rel: 0,
        playerVars: {
            modestBranding: 1,
            showinfo: 0,
            html5: 1,
            controls: 0
        },
        loop: 1,
        start: 10

    });

}
```

It works as intended on the iOS 7 browser and Chrome on Android. However, on the Android stock browser (tested on HTC one) the following behaviour is exhibited:

1. The video starts from the beginning not from the start point
2. The video DOES recognise the end parameter and stops playing
3. On the Android stock browser, the embedded player looks different to the embedded player in Android Chrome on the same device. Before the video loads its a grey, embossed design.

Does anyone know how to get the start point working?

Thanks

Comment: Just wanted to add, I have also tested this by just simply dropping 

<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KWiSZk0z60U?start=100" frameborder="0"></iframe>

with no additional functionality into the page and I still get the same behaviour

Comment: youtubePlayer.seekTo() does not work either